# Data binding Checkboxes using Knockout Observable Arrays

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm trying to reimplement a student attendance example from the Udacity JavaScript Design Patterns course. So far I've managed to recreate the table and correctly populate it with some student data, however it appears when I change a checkbox value this isn't updated in the model.

For example, when I display

```
    debugVM.studentList()[0].days();
```

in the console the output displays the initial attendance data instead of the current state of the checkboxes. A JSFiddle for this can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/blogscot/2pcnuw0x/4/).

index.html

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student</th>
      <!-- ko foreach: attendance -->
      <th data-bind="html: $data"></th>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: studentList">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="html: name, click: $parent.debugStudent"></td>
      <!-- ko foreach: days -->
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checkedValue: $data, checked: $data" />
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js

```
var Student = function(student){

  this.name = ko.observable(student.name);
  this.days = ko.observableArray(student.days);
};


var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.attendance = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]);
  this.studentList = ko.observableArray([]);

  students.forEach(function(student) {
    self.studentList.push(new Student(student));
  });

  self.debugStudent = function() {
    console.log(self.studentList()[0].days());
  };
};
var debugVM = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(debugVM);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the knockout [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects

In your case this means that `days` should be not observable array, but array of observables.

For example you can add new viewModel `Day`:

```
var Day = function(isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked);
}
```

And set the `days` property like this

```
this.days = [];
for (var i = 0; i< student.days.length; i++) {
   this.days.push(new Day(student.days[i] == 1));
}
```

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pcnuw0x/5/)